# Where to report a bug on Ubuntu's Launchpad?

Tags: ubuntu, launchpad

I'm trying to file a bug report for Ubuntu's bug reporting system. The bug reporter is Launchpad.

Launchpad is not a package, so I can't file the bug report against anything. From the past, I know that selecting "I don't know" for the package means its sits somewhere and nothing gets done with it.

How does one file a bug report against Ubuntu's Launchpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You file it against the launchpad *project* rather than a package in the ubuntu project: https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. The bug I am trying to file against Launchpad is the "Find Package" functionality is nearly useless. Your answer is a case in point. Another case in point is the package "GDB". Its the real package, but when I invoke their search/chooser, it tells me there are too many results to return (and it returns nothing). So I can't select anything...